# sympy how to compare symbol with list

Tags: python, sympy

I use sympy and i want compare a symbol with a list like that :

```
 >>> sympy.sympify("Eq(x,[])")
```

but that raise an error : `sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: SympifyError: []`

however that works with set :

```
 >>> sympy.sympify("Eq(x,{})")
 Eq(x,{})
```

why that do not works with list and how to compare symbol with list ?

Comment: There is no list type in SymPy because SymPy expressions are immutable and lists are mutable. There is a symbolic tuple though.

Answer (score 1):

It is a design goal of SymPy to not allow non-SymPy objects as arguments, so there is strong bias for this not to work. You can, however, use a tuple (which can be represented with `Tuple` as the argument:

```
>>> Eq(x, ())
Eq(x, ())
>>> _.subs(x, ())  # and _.subs(x, 1) -> False
True
```